# How to tell a lisp reader function to ignore errors during parsing

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, token

I need a way to suppress any error messages raised when parsing code using `read-from-string` so that I can read from `Clojure` code using something like this:

```
(let* ((string-with-code "  '(func UpperCase \"string\")")
       (brace-pos (position #\( string-with-code))
       (end-of-token (+ brace-pos 
                        (position #\Space (subseq string-with-code brace-pos))))
       (first-token (subseq string-with-code (incf brace-pos) end-of-token)))
  (format t "Found function: '~a'" 
          (read-from-string first-token)))
  ;; ==> Found function: 'func'
```

It basically prints the function name from the lisp code in the string. It works Ok until you try to use the dot operator(`.`) as the first item in the list. `Clojure` uses the `.` both to `cons` and to access classes in a Java package and hence valid code like:

```
(defmacro chain
  ([x form] `(. ~x ~form))
  ([x form & more] `(chain (. ~x ~form) ~@more)))
```

would cause an error:

```
*** - READ from #<INPUT STRING-INPUT-STREAM>: token "." not allowed here
```

if I were to walk it printing every function in the code. I want **a way to ignore/suppress the error messages from `read-from-string`** for this code to work preferably without modifying the way the lisp reader works.

**EDIT :**

A complete program:

```
(defvar string-with-code "(defmacro chain
                    ([x form] `(d ~x ~form))
                    ([x form & more] `(chain (. ~x ~form) ~@more)))
    ")

(defvar end-of-token 0)
(defvar first-token 0)

(defun functions-in-string (code)
  (let ((bpos (position #\( code)))
    (unless (null bpos) 
      (setq end-of-token (+ bpos (position #\Space (subseq code bpos))))
      (setq first-token (subseq code (incf bpos) end-of-token))
      (ignore-errors
       (format t "Found function: '~(~A~)'~%" (read-from-string first-token)))
      (functions-in-string (subseq code end-of-token)))))

    ;; (ignore-errors
     ;; (functions-in-string 0 code))

(functions-in-string string-with-code)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Found function: 'defmacro'
Found function: '[x'
Found function: 'd'
Found function: '[x'
Found function: 'chain'
;; You'll get the error below if ignore-errors wraps around the function call
;; *** - READ from #<INPUT STRING-INPUT-STREAM>: token "." not allowed here
```

Comment: What does it mean 'ignore'? Should it do anything useful? Just return with no result?

Comment: Lisp has notoriously simple syntax, but parsing it the way you do is... well, not really a good idea. I'd suggest you look into `cl-yacc`. This will make your life much easier, and, as a side effect, will also solve this one particular problem with dot character.

Comment: It's not really a good idea to parse Clojure code with a Common Lisp reader. One approach would be to reprogram the reader to accept things like dots as symbols and similar things. You don't need to write a Clojure parser, but one which can read Clojure s-expressions.

Comment: @wvxvw, I shudder at the thought of venturing into `yacc`. It may not be worth the effort to learn a new language in order to solve this...

Comment: That is _not_ a complete program.  When I compile it, I get undefined variable warnings for `end-of-token` and `first-token`, and a style warning that `start-pos` is never used.

Comment: That's one pedantic compiler. Which implementation are you using?

Comment: @Segfault yacc isn't a language, I'm talking about this: https://github.com/jech/cl-yacc . It's too late today to write a parser, but I'll post one tomorrow, it shouldn't be more then some 30-50 loc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear what you are asking, but ignoring errors simply is:

```
CL-USER 37 > (ignore-errors (read-from-string "(. foo bar)"))
NIL
#<CONDITIONS:SIMPLE-READER-ERROR 402000243B>
```

In case of an error, `IGNORE-ERRORS` returns `NIL` and as the second return value the condition.

If you want more control, you would need to write an error handler.

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant ignore as in run the program without telling me about the error. I've tried `ignore-errors` with the program(see edit) and it suppresses all output. I want it to print the functions it found and when it encounters the `.`, it should skip it. Kinda like a try catch block. I took a cursory look at `handler-case` in the hyperspec and it requires the error name. This error doesn't seem to have one.

Comment: Yeaah, reprogramming the reader was my boundary. I'm not that good a lisp programmer. I managed to make it work the way I wanted by taking the `ignore-errors` block to where the string is read from. I'll just have to work with this for now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start for Clojure yacc parsers. This needs more attention from you to deal with special Clojure reader macros and possibly ensure some other grammar aspects, but this is already a functioning start:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defun print-args (&rest args) (format nil "~{~a~^ ~}" args) ))

(defun clojure-lexer (stream)
  (let ((digits '(#\0 #\1 #\2 #\3 #\4 #\5 #\6 #\7 #\8 #\9))
        (translations (make-hash-table)))
    (loop :for (key . value) :in
       '((#\( . oparen)
         (#\) . cparen)
         (#\[ . obracket)
         (#\] . cbracket)
         (#\' . squote)
         (#\` . accent)
         (#\: . colon)
         (#\, . comma)
         (#\@ . at)) :do
       (setf (gethash key translations) value))
    (labels ((%reverse-coerce (collected)
               (coerce (nreverse collected) 'string))
             (%read-token ()
               (loop
                  :with collected := nil
                  :and stringp := nil
                  :and commentp := nil
                  :for token := (read-char stream nil nil) :do
                  (cond
                    ((null token)
                     (return (and collected (%reverse-coerce collected))))
                    ((char= token #\;)
                     (push token collected)
                     (setf commentp t))
                    ((char= token #\")
                     (if commentp
                         (push token collected)
                         (if stringp
                             (progn
                               (push token collected)
                               (return (%reverse-coerce collected)))
                             (if collected
                                 (progn
                                   (unread-char token)
                                   (return (%reverse-coerce collected)))
                                 (progn
                                   (push token collected)
                                   (setf stringp t))))))
                    ((gethash token translations)
                     (if (or stringp commentp)
                         (push token collected)
                         (if collected
                             (progn
                               (unread-char token stream)
                               (return (%reverse-coerce collected)))
                             (return (gethash token translations)))))
                    ((member token '(#\Newline #\Rubout))
                     (if commentp
                         (return (and collected (%reverse-coerce collected)))
                         (if stringp
                             (push token collected)
                             (and collected (return (%reverse-coerce collected))))))
                    ((member token '(#\Space #\Tab))
                     (if (or stringp commentp)
                         (push token collected)
                         (and collected (return (%reverse-coerce collected)))))
                    (t (push token collected))))))
      (lambda ()
        (let* ((key (%read-token))
               (value (or (gethash key translations) key)))
          (if (null key)
              (values nil nil)
              (let ((terminal
                     (cond
                       ((member key '(oparen cparen squote colon accent
                                      comma at obracket cbracket))
                        key)
                       ((or (member (char key 0) digits)
                            (and (char= (char key 0) #\-)
                                 (> (length key) 1)
                                 (member (char key 1) digits)))
                        'number)
                       ((char= (char key 0) #\") 'string)
                       ((char= (char key 0) #\;) 'comment)
                       (t 'id))))
                (values terminal value))))))))

(yacc:define-parser *clojure-parser*
  (:start-symbol exp)
  (:terminals (id oparen cparen squote colon accent
                  comma at obracket cbracket string number))

  (exp
   (oparen id exp-list cparen #'print-args)
   (oparen id cparen #'print-args)
   (obracket exp-list cbracket #'print-args)
   (obracket cbracket #'print-args)
   (comment #'print-args)
   (accented-exp #'print-args)
   (quoted-exp #'print-args)
   (term #'print-args))

  (term id string number)
  (quoted-exp (quote exp))
  (accented-exp (accent exp) (accent at exp))
  (exp-list (exp exp-list) exp))

(defun parse-clojure (string)
  (yacc:parse-with-lexer
   (clojure-lexer (make-string-input-stream string)) *clojure-parser*))

(parse-clojure
 "(defn str-invoke [instance method-str & args]
            (clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod 
                \"instance\" 123 
                method-str 
                (to-array args)))")
```

Results in:

```
;; "OPAREN defn (str-invoke
;;              (OBRACKET (instance (method-str (& args))) CBRACKET
;;               OPAREN clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod (\"instance\"
;;                                                     (123
;;                                                      (method-str
;;                                                       OPAREN to-array args CPAREN))) CPAREN)) CPAREN"
```

---

Here's the BNF for the above grammar (not claiming it is the Clojure grammar, it only reflects the Lisp code above):

```
exp ::= '(' id exp-list ')'
      | '(' id ')'
      | '[' exp-list ']'
      | '[' ']'
      | ';' /[^\n]*/
      | accented-exp
      | quoted-exp
      | term

term ::= id | '"' /[^"]*/ '"' | /-?[0-9][^\s]+/
quoted-exp ::= '\'' exp
accented-exp ::= '`' exp | '`' '@' exp
exp-list ::= exp exp-list | exp
id ::= /[^()[\]:,`@']+/
```

For simplicity, some parts are given as regular expressions, those are delimited by `//`.

Comment: don't know what to say. I barely understand it. How does it work?

Comment: @Segfault you probably want to read [here](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/cl-yacc/cl-yacc.html) first. The general idea is that you have a lexer and a parser. Lexer (aka tokenizer) reads a single terminal from the stream, parser calls the lexer to get next token. The parser uses a formal grammar definition for the language to build the AST of what it reads. I've added some callback to simply print what the parser sees, but you'd put your function in place of this callback. The lexer turned out to be more complex then I hoped, but the parser is still simple.

Comment: PS. The lexer as of now doesn't handle escape character and dot character + I don't know what other reader macros there are in Clojure, but other then that it should be mostly functional.